# Drawable Selector is not working for Layout in the Nexus Devices

Tags: android

In My application setting a background of Relative layout as

```
<item android:drawable="@color/box_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/box_pressed"  android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/box_default" android:state_selected="false"></item>
```

The layout is used in the  Adapter.But in case of Nexus device the selector is not working when i tap on the layout first time. please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

the actual problem lies in a defect in android 3.2 regarding hardware acceleration so if you put in your `AndroidManifest` that your application is `hardwareAccelerated="true"` your problem will be solved.

Comment: Added the android:Clickable="true" its working form me.